# Amenability, growth and asymptotic dimension

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, amenability

I recently found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3076930/is-there-any-relationship-between-growth-rate-and-amenability) on MSE, relating growth of groups with whether they are amenable, elementary amenable or not. I would like to know if there is an extra relation to finite or infinite asymptotic dimension. Taken from the linked question, we have the table

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc} \text{amenable/growth} & \text{polynomial} & \text{intermediate} &\text{exponential} \\
\hline
\text{no} & \varnothing & \varnothing & F_2 \\
\text{elementary} & \Bbb Z & \varnothing & BS(1,n)\\
\text{yes but not elementary} & \varnothing & \Gamma & \Bbb Z/(2)\wr\Gamma\end{array}$$

The example of a non-amenable group given here is $\mathbb{F}_2$, which has finite asymptotic dimension. What about an example for this cell that has infinite asymptotic dimension? I guess something like $\mathbb{F}_2\times\mathbb{Z}^2\times\mathbb{Z}^3\times\dots$ would be an example of a non-amenable group of infinite asymptotic dimension, no?

As for elementary amenable groups, by Chou's theorem these have either polynomial or exponential growth. For polynomial growth, the easiest examples are $\mathbb{Z}^d$, which have finite asymptotic dimension. Now by Gromov's theorem, every group of polynomial growth is elementary amenable. Does there exist a group of polynomial growth with infinite asymptotic dimension?

What about elementary amenable groups of exponential growth? Do we have examples of finite and infinite asymptotic dimension?

Finally, for amenable, but not elementary amenable groups, we have either intermediate or exponential growth. The classical example of intermediate growth is the Grigorchuk group, which has infinite asymptotic dimension from what I've heard. Does there exist a group of intermediate growth that has finite asymptotic dimension? Finally, what about amenable, not elementary amenable groups of exponential growth? Do we have examples of finite and infinite asymptotic dimension?

I have not had much interraction with groups so I understand that what I'm asking could be very elementary, but I couldn't find any good source on this, so here I am.

Comment: Just regarding the Grigorchuk group $G$, it has infinite asymptotic dimension by the following argument: $G \times G$ is commensurable to $G$. You can find a coarse embedding of $\mathbf{Z}$ in $G$ so you can find a coarse embedding of $\mathbf{Z}^d$ in $G$ for all $d>0$, so the asymptotic dimension cannot be finite.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda I see, thanks for the argument.

Comment: I don't know about most of these questions, and don't know whether they are known or not, but $\mathbb{F}_\infty$ also has asymptotic dimension 1, as it's a tree.

Comment: @DiegoMartínez Oh right. I guess the counter-example would be something like $\times_{d=1}^\infty\mathbb{Z}^d\times\mathbb{F}_2$. This is non-amenable as it contains a non-amenable subgroup, it has subgroups of arbitrarily large asymptotic dimension, so it has infinite asymptotic dimension. Thanks for your comment, I'll edit that part.

Comment: 1) Polynomial growth implies virtually nilpotent, hence finite asdim. 2) Infinite asdim and non-amenable: there are many examples: $\mathbf{Z}\wr G$ whenever $G$ is non-amenable, Thompson's groups $T$ and $V$, etc. 3) Infinite asdim and amenable but not el-amenable: $\mathbf{Z}\wr G$ works whenever $G$ is amenable and not el-amenable. Other examples are topological-full-groups of minimal subshifts, the f.p. ascending HNN of Grigorchuk's groups. 4) Infinite asdim and el-amenable: $\mathbf{Z}\wr\mathbf{Z}$, also many f.p. metabelian groups.

Comment: @YCor Thanks. Also, the lamplighter group $\mathbb{Z}_2\wr\mathbb{Z}$ is an example of an elementary amenable group with finite asdim and exponential growth, right? So I guess there are two boxes left to fill: a) intermediate growth and finite asdim (which is automatically amenable and non-elementary amenable) and b) exponential growth, amenable, non-elementary amenable and finite asdim. Do you also have any insight on these two?

Comment: These two form a single box to fill: finite asdim, amenable and not el-amenable. I don't even have reasonable candidates. (I believe Nekrashevych' groups in https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.01033 have infinite asdim although I haven't checked, so for the moment they could still be considered as unlikely candidates.)

Comment: Where did I say or suggest this??? and of course it's false, there are many polycyclic groups of exp growth, they have finite asdim and are amenable. I was just saying I don't know of any amenable but not el-amenable group with finite asdim.

Comment: @YCor I got confused with the phrasing "these form a single box to fill". It seemed like "the other box" was empty under that phrasing. I will delete that comment.